# error importing module with python nosetest

Tags: python, nose

I'm trying to test one class that imports another class that I've written, but I receive an error when I run nosetest.

my package file structure is something like this:

```
./__init__.py
./classA.py
./classB.py
./tests
    ./__init__.py
    ./testClassA.py
```

Where classA.py imports B like:

```
from classB import B

class A:
    def __init__(self):
       self.b=B() 
       ...
```

When I run nosetest, testClassA.py the tries to import A, it throws an error message.

testClassA.py has an import statement like this:

```
from ..classA import A
```

and the error message I receive is like this:

```
ImportError: no module named 'classB'
```

Comment: You should add the path to sys.path, `import sys; if PATH_TO_SCRIPTS_STRING not in sys.path: sys.append(PATH_TO_SCRIPTS_STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer using imports with the complete package inner path in the modules inside your package, like this:

```
from mypackage.classA import A
```

only inconvenience is if you have lots of imports and then later change your mind about the package name, you'll have to replace it in every file.